# What is the most convenient coordinates format to store data for spatial queries: WGS84 or OSGB36?

Tags: postgis

I have datasets that come in different coordinate formats as WGS84 (4326) and OSGB36 (27700).
Clients are consuming the "published" data as format WGS84.
So at the moment, all the data since the earliest stages are saved as WGS84.
However all the intermediate transformations are based on ST_Intersects, ST_DWithin, etc. So can I consider as rule of thumb: working with data as OSGB36 for faster calculations (cartesian coordinates) and converting to WGS84 only for the published data?

Comment: Probably. If you use ST_Transform in conjunction with ST_Intersects in a query, then the index will most likely not be used. So, if you are doing analytical work in 27700, and you have a spatial index on that, it will be faster, and converting to WGS84 for consumption (I assume you mean in WMS, WFS or something simillar) will have less overhead.

Comment: Yes you got right I guess what I was trying to say :) I think I should in the "datawarehouse" working only with cartesian coordinates (OSGB36) and only at the end, converting them to WGS84.

Comment: Do all your data come from area where 27700 is valid or do you play also with worldwide or continental data?

Comment: Just UK for the moment

Comment: We maintain all our spatial data in PostGIS in WGS84, but ETL the data to our analysts using MSSQL Server in Colorado State Plane (feet) so the spatial functions all return values in feet without having to transform the data (which they can't anyway as MSSQL Server lacks that function!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should work with the data in OSGB because

- users will be more familiar with the inputs and outputs for checking
- assuming the data came from osgb it will be more accurate to undertake transformations in that coordinate system
- you are more likely to already have an index
- you get sensible units as distances and areas, etc.

What you could do is have a materialized view with the data in WGS84 with `create materialized view xxx as select ..... ,ST_Transform(osgb_geom,4326) as geom_wgs84 from my_table`, and refresh it manually, or even create your own shadow table and set triggers on osgb data to refresh the view on an event (e.g. a data insert) or interval of your choosing (perhaps via a helper script). You then get constant ETL inside the database if that is what you need (providing your db can cope with the load, depending on how you set the refresh conditions).

Comment: I am not sure I got properly all your points. I think users are usually more familiar with wgs84 than osgb36. Another point is that I build most of the indexes so doesnt really change. About sensible units I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Depends on the users I guess - I would say most UK GIS users would be more familiar with the OSGB coordinate system, and know the bounds better than lat lon (although it is handy that the 0 meridian passes through London!). And a distance result in metres makes a lot more sense than in degrees (which is what you get when running geometry calculations in WGS84). Obviously you can convert, but that's another step. Or use geography (https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography). Indexes, fair enough. I think it's fairly marginal either way, but that's what I would do